# Card draw simulation not returning values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to simulate rounds of drawing 2 cards and picking the card with the higher value from a diminishing deck.

Each area of the code seems to work except the final return of the playHistory array which is blank when I return it to Google Sheets. No error, no data. If I only call the playCard function or return the deck array both print the correct values.

```js
//Global Vars
var deck = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
var playHistory = [];
var cardsPlayed = -1; //So first card played is index 0 in playHistory array

function simGame(turns) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < turns; i++) {
    playCard();
  }

  return playHistory;
}


function playCard() {
  var draw1 = 0;
  var draw2 = 0;

  draw1 = [deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length), 1)];
  draw2 = [deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length), 1)];
  if (draw1 > draw2) {
    playHistory.push(draw1);
  } else {
    playHistory.push(draw2);
  }
  
  cardsPlayed = cardsPlayed + 1;
  return playHistory[cardsPlayed];
}
```

Comment: You never call any of the functions? You just *define* them but the entire application just defines a bunch of variables and functions, then exits.

Comment: I call them from a cell in Google Sheets. For example, =simGame(3), or =playCard()

Comment: Well, the function works. If you just `console.log(playCard())` in the example, you get a return value. I'm not sure we can diagnose a problem we can't observe, since it doesn't seem to be present here.

Comment: My playCard() works too. It's when I call simGame() that playHistory doesn't return anything.

Comment: `simGame` also works as expected. Here, at least. Again, I am unable to reproduce the problem you describe - I don't know what's wrong or how you expect us to solve it.

Comment: It must be something up with google sheets then - I'll head that way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your function works as expected, it might not return what you expect. The result of calling simGame(), is an array filled with doubly nested arrays, since you wrap your splice in an array. And splice already returns an array. So an example result of simGame(3) is `[[[3]],[[2]],[[1]]]`. Is this a format google sheets expects?

Comment: @Shilly No. Google sheets expects a 2 dimensional array. ``@bulkhed`` You have unnecessary nesting of the array.

Comment: I think that's definately the problem @Shilly.

Comment: Remove the enclosing brackets around the splice function.

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to leave a clear solution, the issue was related to a syntax mistake:

```
  draw1 = [deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length), 1)];
  draw2 = [deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length), 1)];
```

Where the splice is unnecessarily enclosed between brackets:

```
  draw1 = deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length), 1);
  draw2 = deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not worth an answer but when you run your function, the correct data returns? I guess the problem lies in your google sheets and not your JS.

```js
//Global Vars
var deck = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
var playHistory = [];
var cardsPlayed = -1; //So first card played is index 0 in playHistory array

console.log(simGame(3));

function simGame(turns) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < turns; i++) {
    playCard();
  }

  return playHistory;
}


function playCard() {
  var draw1 = 0;
  var draw2 = 0;

  draw1 = [deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length), 1)];
  draw2 = [deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length), 1)];
  if (draw1 > draw2) {
    playHistory.push(draw1);
  } else {
    playHistory.push(draw2);
  }
  
  cardsPlayed = cardsPlayed + 1;
  return playHistory[cardsPlayed];
}
```

Comment: I suppose what is confusing me, is that if I return the array deck or the playHistory array from playCard() it returns correctly. Yet if I return the array playHistory (from the simGame() function) it's blank.

Comment: Well that's not true as you can see here. After the global vars i call "console.log(simGame(3));" This will eventually return playHistory and this is not empty.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with Google Sheets display. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I made this simpler by shuffling the deck beforehand with [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) and then [popping](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp) from the deck instead of splicing. All you have to do to shuffle with randojs is say `randoSequence(deck)`.

```js
var deck = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];

function simGame(turns) {
  var playHistory = []
  var shuffledDeck = randoSequence(deck);
  for (var i = 0; i < turns && shuffledDeck.length > 0; i++) {
    var draw1 = (shuffledDeck.pop() || {value: 0}).value;
    var draw2 = (shuffledDeck.pop() || {value: 0}).value;
    playHistory.push(Math.max(draw1, draw2));
  }
  return playHistory;
}

console.log(simGame(5));
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Check out randojs's website if you have questions about that. If you have a question about anything else, leave me a comment and I'll be happy to help more. I think the most confusing part might be this:

```
(shuffledDeck.pop() || {value: 0}).value
```

It's just saying that if the `shuffledDeck` array is empty and `pop()` therefore returns `undefined`, use the value `0` as a default instead of allowing `undefined.value` to execute, which would cause an error.